# T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

people
I need your help, please. 
I have an application in Cake PHP, it was working perfectly and  simply stopped working by emitting the following error:

> Notice (8): Undefined variable: authUser
>   [APP/View/Elements/top_bar.ctp, line 20]
>
> Fatal Error Error: syntax error, unexpected ''logoutRedirect''
>   (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ')'    File:
>   /var/www/pegasus/instancias/pw/Controller/AppController.php    Line: 20

“In my homologation environment . everything works perfectly. I compared the codes and they are the same. I checked the database. Everything is ok and nothing has changed on the server.”

```
class AppController extends Controller {

    public $global = [];
    public $components = array(
        'Cookie',
        'Session',
        'AuthManager.AccessPermission',
        'TaskManager.TaskService',
        'AuthManager.LogSystem',
        'ConfigManager.Configuration',
        'Auth' => array(
            'loginRedirect'      => array(
                    'plugin'     => null,
                    'controller' => 'home',
                    'action'     => 'index'
            )
             'logoutRedirect'     => array(
                    'plugin'     => 'auth_manager',
                    'controller' => 'users',
                    'action'     => 'login'
            ),
            //'authorize' => array('Controller'),
            'authError'     => 'Você deve fazer login para ter acesso a essa área!',
            'loginError'    => 'Combinação de usuário e senha errada!' ,
            'authenticate'  => array(
                'Form'      => array(
                    'scope' => array('User.status' => '1')
                ),
            )
```

Comment: Missing comma (`,`)after the `)` in the line before

Comment: **Thank you**, a ( ; ) and another error in the View of the Users caused the problem, I was confused as they are the same as the homologation, and were working perfectly, it's been 2 years that the system is in the air.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `,` before `'logoutRedirect'`:

```
'loginRedirect'  => array(
    'plugin'     => null,
    'controller' => 'home',
    'action'     => 'index',
),
'logoutRedirect' => array(
    'plugin'     => 'auth_manager',
    'controller' => 'users',
    'action'     => 'login',
),
```

---

Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18092288/5447994) to know the explanation for the error `T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING`. **5. Array lists** is the one matches yours.

Comment: and `));` at the end

Comment: May be we can assume that this code is the snippet - Not the complete class

Comment: I meant that this is an incomplete array.